# Cartalyst Sentinel - Log events (What is the right way)

Tags: php, cartalyst-sentinel

Where will be the right place to Log of every Signup and Signin attempt inside Sentinel?

I'm looking to store: status (succeful or not), time stamp, IP, HTTP User Agent, HTTP Accept Language.

I had think to put them inside IlluminateUserRepository.php into the functions recordLogin and create, but I'm not sure if this would be the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Sentinel hooks available and add listeners to your boot() method in EventServiceProvider.